# php comparing two password strings

Tags: php, explode, strcmp

I'm using explode() to convert a string read from a text file to an array, which I use to compare with input from a user.

The text file contains:

```
 user#test //user= username test= password
```

When I try to use strcmp() it returns -1 even though printing the two string variables results with an output of

```
test||test
=-1
```

which I print with:

```
if(isset($user_details[1])){
$user_details = explode('#', $user);     //   $user is text file
$passW = $_GET['password'];              //   input: "test"
$tesPW = user_details[1];
printf($passW."||".$testPW."=".strcmp($passW,$testPW));
}
```

Comment: You should never compare plaintext passwords. http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: You're printing all on one line with your `printf` statement, yet it's outputting on two lines.  That tells me that `$testPW` ends in a newline

Comment: try to use `$tesPW = trim(user_details[1]);`

Comment: @Devin_Kinh you got some advance?

Comment: @Devin_Kinh you solved your problem? Don't forget check one answer as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a simple app for a select group of folks in a limited environment, I will avoid commenting on the security issues related to this method.

This function will return `true` if the user/pass match a line in the file, `false` if not.

```
//Assumes const USERACCOUNTFILE defines the path to the file
function AuthenticateUser ($username, $password) {
    $handle = @fopen(USERACCOUNTFILE, "r"); //Open the file for reading
    if ($handle) {
        while(($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) { //Read each line of the file
            $line = explode('#', $line); //Split the line
            if($line && count($line) == 2) { //Does the line have the expected number of values?
                //Compare the values minus all whitespace
                if(trim($line[0], "\r\n\t ") === $username && trim($line[1], "\r\n\t ") === $password) {
                    fclose($handle);
                    return true; //Found a match
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    return false; //None matched
}
```

You may also use `trim($line[0])` without the optional parameter of `"\r\n\t "`, as the default parameter sufficient.

Comment: you can skip `\r\n\t ` part as by default trim removes them, actually list is `" \t\n\r\0\x0B`

Comment: I like being explicit, especially for examples.  I will update the answer, though, to state that it is optional.

Comment: _Never_ use loose comparison of strings with `==` on passwords, usernames etc. In PHP, `"password"==0` is true, so `AuthenticateUser(0, 0)` will be true and `AuthenticateUser('test', 0)` will be true for existing user `test`, no matter what the password is. Instead, at least use strict comparison with `===`. Even better, consider `password_verify()`.

Comment: @ChristopherK. You make a good point. In this case both items being compared will likely be strings coming from both a text file and a text field in a UI, so type comparison isn't strictly necessary, but someone seeing this and adapting it to their purposes may not know that.

Answer (score 0):

if strcmp return -1 is due to $passW is less than $testPW http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php.

If $user have the string "user#test //user= username test= password" and you make $user_details = explode('#', $user); you have in user_details[1]; the string "test //user= username test= password";